# What is the function from which all other functions can be derived?

Tags: function, computer-science

I seem to remember reading about a function that could be used to make all other functions. Does anyone know what it is? And how could such a function be used?

I can't remember where I read it and my google-fu is not strong enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are thinking about [combinator calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus), and there especially the iota combinator mentioned at the bottom of [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus#Informal_description).

Comment: I think you and Paul got the right answer but can anyone give a simpler explanation for ιx = xSK? I don't quite follow the wikipedia explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You may mean: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus

Or: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine

Or: eval